# How to see an average of I/O of disk with iotop command?

Tags: linux, iotop

With `iotop -o` command I can see the write and read speed of the disk per second. But it varies a lot, from 0 to high values. I'd like to see an average of it per minute or per 10 seconds.

How can I do it?

Comment: `sudo iotop -od 10` and `sudo iotop -od 60` will show averages of 10 s and 1 min.

Answer (score 1):

I hope `sar` is the better way to get the average result

```
 sar -d 1 10 | awk '/Average/ {print $2" "$4*0.000512"MB/s  "$5*0.000512"MB/s"}' | sed 's#DEV.*#DEV rd_sec/s wr_sec/s#' | column -t
```

- `rd_sec/s` and `wr_sec/s` are number of sectors read and write from the device. The size of a sector is 512 bytes.
- multiply by `.000512` to convert into MB/sec

Comment: Is there a way to list in MB/s?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos check my updated answer