# Disk io stat “averaged” over a period of time

Tags: linux, performance, disk, iostat

I am using the iostat utility on my RedHat Linux server to monitor the performance of a disk. When I use "iostat -xd sdh 1", I get the perf result printed every one second. When I use "iostat -xd sdh 5", I get the perf result printed every five second. My feeling is the latter command is printing a snapshot of the perf every five second, rather than averaging over the past 5 seconds. Am I correct in my understanding?

If so, is there a way I can make iostat print the perf. number averaged over n seconds, or is there some other utility that will do that.

Currently, the perf number is fluctuating within a range, and I want to get a somewhat "stable" number. I am hoping that averaging over a period of time will give me such a number.

Thank you, Ahmed.

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/463070/117549

Answer (score 1):

We can read from [IOSTAT(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat):

> The first report generated by the iostat command provides statistics
>   concerning the time since the system was booted. Each subsequent
>   report covers the time since the previous report.

If you need a long-term report to see average IO statistics since boot, i.e. so called by you "stable number", you have to use `watch` utility:

```
watch -n 1 iostat -xd sdh 5 2
```

The `5 2` in the last command means *"display 2 reports at 5 seconds interval"*. With `watch` utility you'll see always at first line average "static" statistics since system boot which will be  changed relatively slow and at second line "dynamic" statistics with "real-time" numbers. Due to `watch` utility the first "stable/slow" line will be updated every 5 seconds too.

Consider to add `-t` option to see each report time:

```
watch -n 1 iostat -xtd sdh 5 2
```

Try to see more "dynamic" reports:

```
watch -n 1 iostat -xtd sdh 5 3
```